# How to get the Tree of all Accounts from Google Ads API?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

There are 2 types of Google Ads Account. Direct Account and a Manager Account.

I need to list down all the ad accounts. The Manager account must be excluded, but the accounts linked under it must be populated.

Here is what I have tried till now:

First I'm making a GET request to the below URL:

```
 URL: 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v1/customers:listAccessibleCustomers?key=XXXXXX',
```

I'm fetching the Ad Accounts linked to the Gmail Account. I have 4 Ad Accounts.

1,2,3 are normal Ad Accounts. 4 is a Manager Account, which has 2 Ad Accounts linked to it.

I'm able to fetch them using the below query hitting the below URL:

```
https://googleads.googleapis.com/v2/customers/'+selectedCustomerID+'/googleAds:search


SELECT customer.id,  customer.resource_name, customer.descriptive_name, customer.manager, customer.test_account FROM  customer_client where customer.id ="+ selectedCustomerID
```

This returns data something like this:

For Account 1 and 3, I'm getting the below error:

```
The caller does not have permission
```

For Account 2 I'm getting data.

For Account 4, I'm getting `manager:true` for all the accounts linked under it along with the manager account and I'm receiving 5 accounts under it.

Ideally, I should be receiving 3 accounts with `manager:false` and 1 account with  `manager:true` and 2 sub-accounts under it.

What should be my approach in such case?

Comment: `ListAccessibleCustomers` returns resource names of customers directly accessible by some Google Account. You might filter manager accounts from the response and list all client accounts for manager accounts. Clients accounts are accessible as https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/google.ads.googleads.v2.resources#customerclient. Since clients customers might be managers too you might need some kind of recursion to build an accounts tree

Comment: what is key there ?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working using the customer_client_link service. Bear in mind, the below code slices off the resource names and only returns the hierarchy of CIDs

```
def get_hierarchy(client, customer_id):
ga_service = client.get_service('GoogleAdsService', version='v3')

query = "SELECT customer_client_link.client_customer FROM customer_client_link"

# Issues a search request using streaming.
response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id, query)

try:
    for batch in response:
        for row in batch.results:
            # row.customer_client_link.client_customer contains additional trailing and leading text, but is
            # non-subscriptable so we need to cast it directly then slice the result.
            customer = str(row.customer_client_link.client_customer)
            # Remove the sliding to get the full resource name.
            print(customer[18:-2])
```